# Overload operator []

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I overloaded an operator [], but it's not working as I would like.

```
    class A{
        int *const e;
        const int row, column;
    public:
        int rows() const
        {
            return row;
        }

        int columns() const
        {
            return column;
        }

        int size() const
        {
            return row * column;
        }

        A(int r, int c)
            : row(r), column(c), e(new int[r*c]) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < r*c; i++)
            {
                e[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        virtual int *const operator[ ](int r)
        {
            return &e[r*row];
        }
}
```

For example:
If I wrote:

```
A a(2, 5)
a[0][0] = 1; // OK
a[0][1] = 2; // OK
a[0][2] = 3; // It's assigned a [0][2] == 3 but also [1][0] == 3
```

I could not find the problem. It should assigned a value 3 only to [0][2]
What's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a[0][2]` and `a[1][0]` are one and the same. Let's see:

`&e[r*row]` is the same as `&(*(e+(r*row)))` (by definition of `[]`) which is the same as `(e+(r*row))`.

If `r` is 0, this is just `e`, and if `r` is 1, this is `(e+row)`. Which is, given that your `row` is 2, is `e+2`.

So `a[0]` returns `e` and `a[1]` returns `e+2`.

Now `a[0][2]` is `(a[0])[2]` is `e[2]`, and `a[1][0]` is `(e+2)[0]` is `e[2]`. See? Same thing.

If `row` is the number of rows and `column` is the number of columns, as your intention seems to be, you are better off returning `&e[r*column]` from your `operator[]` (because the number of columns is the *size* of one row).

Comment: Oh okay, I've changed but I've still the same problem

Comment: If you changed it correctly you cannot have the same problem. You may have a similar problem but not the same.

Comment: Yes, but I mean that result is the same

Comment: I'm so sorry, your answer is okay. I had mistake in print function.